# How are Handles managed properly?

Tags: c++, handle

This is a very basic question about the correct use of a HANDLE. Given the following code (it is not a particular source file):

```
typedef void* HANDLE;

HANDLE myHandle;

myHandle = SomeObject;

//...some elaborate code...//
```

1. First question: Is myHandle now located on the Stack or Heap? Since a Handle can be a pointer as well as just an index I am not quite sure about that.

   At the point myHandle is out of scope it is removed (at least I think so). But in case it is a class member it remains visible until the owning object was deleted. So second question:
2. If I want to avoid any further access to myHandle, is it good practice to do

   ```
   myHandle = 0;  // I do not need this handle anymore
   ```

   Would I run into a conflict with memory management now, or any other restrictions regarding managed code? Are there other options to state that this handle should not be used anymore similar to pointers:

   ```
   mypointer = NULL;
   ```

EDIT: I was talking about garbage collection in first place which is obviously not included in c++. This is a part of [managed extensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Managed_Extensions_for_C%2B%2B). Thanks for helping me out with this fatal error!

Comment: "Pointer as well as index"? "Removed by garbage collector"? What's going on here... maybe start from the beginning. This question makes little sense.

Comment: First of all I strongly suggest you read more about C++ memory management, since there are no garbage collectors in C++. In case you are referring to WinAPI handles, you should call CloseHandle(handle) on handles after you are done with them. But again, you should study C++ memory management or you'll have more serious troubles.

Comment: Why do *none* of the answers suggest RAII? Give me an answer that's worth upvoting!

Comment: Well I've encountered a fatal error: By garbage collector I was talking about gc managed code, which is just a derivation of the c++ standard i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably a Java programmer from the assumptions that you make.

The variable `myHandle` is indeed allocated on the stack, and it is removed when it goes out of scope, although not by a garbage collector (no such thing exists in C++).

However, this does **not** free the handle (`myHandle` is just a variable that holds some opaque numeric value, the *actual* handle is owned by the OS -- so its lifetime is not identical to the lifetime of any arbitrary variable holding that value). You must do this yourself using the appropriate API function (for most things that are a `HANDLE`, this is `CLoseHandle`), preferrably with a "handle holder" class so it is exception-safe.

A simple implementation of such a handle holder could look like this:

```
class AutoHandle
{
    HANDLE handle;
public:
    AutoHandle(HANDLE in) : handle(in) {}
    ~AutoHandle() { CloseHandle(handle); }
};
```

That way, you assign to a AutoHandle variable when opening a resource, and when it goes out of scope, the handle *is closed*. You cannot forget to do it, and it will even work if an exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

As you have not specified what `HANDLE`s you are talking about, I assume Windows handles.

A `HANDLE` is an opaque data-type (mostly represents a number the OS can work with) and should be treated only by system-functions such as `CreateFile` or `CloseHandle`.

You should never set a `HANDLE` to `0` by yourself as you are losing the associated resource.

See [CloseHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx), [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx)(especially the Return Value), and [Windows Data Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751(v=vs.85).aspx).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handle_(computing))

> In computer programming, a handle is an abstract reference to a resource. Handles are used when application software references blocks of memory or objects managed by another system, such as a database or an operating system.
>
> While a pointer literally contains the address of the item to which it refers, a handle is an abstraction of a reference which is managed externally; its opacity allows the referent to be relocated in memory by the system without invalidating the handle, which is impossible with pointers. The extra layer of indirection also increases the control the managing system has over operations performed on the referent. Typically the handle is an index or a pointer into a global array of tombstones.

---

And C++ does not have a garbage collection by the Standard, this is why you need to delete `new`ed objects yourself, but not handles given by the system!

Answer (score 0):

Usually prefer to use delete before put a pointer to NULL.

But for a HANDLER don't put it to NULL yourself !